# Trying to use Visual studio IDE (Find & Replace) as a quick & dirty regex tool but stucked

Tags: regex, ide, visual-studio-2005

I have a xml text file opened in VS2005 IDE.

It has 4 mocked up lines:

```
<mc id="dog" name="mydogBob"/>
<mc id="cat" name="katie"/>
<mc id="turtle" name="slow"/>
<mc id="fish" name="happy"/>
```

How do I use VS2005 Find/Replace function with regular expression to replace words and make the final result like:

```
dog
cat
turtle
fish
```

Thank you so much

-Simon

Answer (score 5):

Find What:

```
^.*id="{.*}" .*$
```

Replace With:

```
\1
```

In Find options check *Use* and select *Regular Expressions* from the dropdown.

Comment: that would return: `dog" name="mydogBob`   as the first result.

Comment: `^.*id="([^"]+)" .*$`  try that.